# Java script for web browser to create shortcut name for web URL/ local network page

Tags: javascript, browser

I am trying to get a solution to have less number of characters to be used to access local web pages within the local network.

Please suggest what scripting/ programming language would be good? I was thinking to write java script.

Thanks,
Vinay